# 1D Convolutional Neural Network Input Shape `ValueError`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am generating a 1D Convolution and have some trouble with the input shape of my data. I had a look at some posts and it seems the error was that the data has to be 3D but my data is already 3D.

```
# shape
# x_train shape: (1228, 1452, 20)
# y_train shape: (1228, 1452, 8)
# x_val shape: (223, 680, 20)
# x_val shape: (223, 680, 8)

###
n_outputs = 8
n_timesteps = 1452
n_features = 20

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]))) # ie 1452, 20
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=9, 
                batch_size=64, 
                shuffle=True)
```

But I keep on getting this error message:

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (1228, 1452, 8) was passed for an output of shape (None, 8) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

What I gather from this is that target shape which is 3 dimensional is not the same as the 2 dimensional output and so it can't work out the loss, but I just need to find a way to reshape so that they are equal.

*EDIT*
`model.summary()` is shown below

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 1450, 64)          3904      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 1448, 64)          12352     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1448, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 724, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 46336)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 100)               4633700   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 808       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,650,764
Traceback (most recent call last):
Trainable params: 4,650,764
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is possibly your `input_shape` may need another comma to make the batch size ambiguous. Perhaps `input_shape=(1452,20,)` <-- notice the extra comma

Comment: No luck with this I'm afraid

Comment: :( That's because I was being oblivious. It's just like the error says: your `y` values have an unexpected dimension. Notice that `y_train shape: 1228,1452,8` but down at your last Dense layer you've got `n_outputs=8`. What's actually hitting your output is `(batch,1452,8)` but it's expecting `(batch,8)`

Comment: Ah okay, does that mean I have to reshape the y_train.. but if I do, wouldn't that change the order of classification/change dimensions?

Comment: Hmm. `model.summary()` may be helpful. `(1228, 1452, 8)` passing through `Flatten()` would be something like `(1228,11616)` next layer takes it to `(1228,100)`, final prediction layer takes it to `(1228,8)`. If you want to predict among 8 classes for each of 1228 data points, then your prediction layer (and entire network, probably) is fine. If that's what you want, then only use the class columns as `y`. If you're wanting classification at each step along a time series for 1228 data points, then there's some redesigning to be done.

Comment: I've attached the model summary, I wanted to classify out of 8 for each 1228 data point. I.e. a one hot encoded vector length 20 has a single classification of one hot encoded vector length 8. What do you mean by using the class columns only as y?

Comment: :) Precisely that, then: your `y` values should be (only) your one-hot encoded vectors of length 8. The network will only welcome inputs of shape (batch,1452,20) and only outputs shape (batch,8). `y_train` is (batch,1452,8) but needs to be (batch,8). Also, your training and validation shapes don't agree: (batch,1452,20) for training and (batch,680,20) for validation, but (1452 != 680).

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in my case was that the target vector was 3D whilst the output vector was 2D and so there is an obvious mismatch. To fix the issue change the shape of the `y_train` to `(batch, 8)` or use `return_sequences=True` to return the same shape from the previous LSTM layer.